# How to open multple aspx page one by one on page close event

Tags: asp.net

I am working on ASP.net Web application. I have a aspx page called "print.aspx"
I need to write a logic to load again the same page again on closing of that page (pressing the "close" button of that page.

(attached image)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjXjK.jpg)
Can you please guide me how can I achieve this ?

Comment: Hi, I did not understand much with this. Let me explain my requirement in short. I am loading "crystal report (.RPT) file" in aspx page(print.aspx). I have a session variable which holds the list of orders where the order information we are showing it in the report. So I have to load the "print.aspx" for all the orders one by one like once user close and the second order information to be displayed in the same aspx file on closing that aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I think The best way to use Thread's and implement async method's with await...

Comment: Hi, I did not understand much with this. Let me explain my requirement in short. I am loading "cystal report (.RPT) file" in aspx page(print.aspx). I have a session variable which holds the list of orders where the order information we are showing it in the report. So I have to load the "print.aspx" for all the orders one by one like once user close and the second order information to be displayed in the same aspx file on closing that aspx page,